# PDF/A-1a and PDF/A-1b in LaTeX documents

Tags: pdf, archiving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate PDF/A and PDF/X?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-to-generate-pdf-a-and-pdf-x)

It looks like it is not easy to obtain a PDF/A-1a compliant PDF file with LaTeX/PDFLaTeX. One complain could be missing TreeRoot and MarkInfo. Anyway, the PDF/A-1b format is less restrictive and easier to get. In general, do you have specific LaTeX strategies to make sure that your final files will be compliant with long term archiving rules?

Comment: It seems quite similar to [How to generate PDF/A and PDF/X?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/576)

Comment: one comment on this: in the search bar, the keyword `PDF/A` returns this single result: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33280/pdf-conformance-tool